# How is forecasting volatility useful?

Tags: volatility

How is volatility useful - from a purely profiteering perspective?

If a quant has good in sample volatility forecasts what can they do with this information? How are options and futures useful? What other financial products can assist them to profit?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward would be trading volatility swaps. If not liquid you can create a proxy for being long/short volatility using options such as calls/ puts for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you think volatility is going to be higher than other people think, and you are right, you can make money by buying options. If you think volatility is going to be lower than other people think, and you are right, you can make money by selling options. So all those who trade options (and other derivatives that resemble options) are highly concerned about volatility.

Futures prices are not much affected by volatility, with one exception of course: *volatility futures*